# C# webClient->DownloadFile download don't start

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, download, webclient

I'm an absolutely beginner in C#-Programming and have one stupid Problem. I only like to download files, which are in the temporatry directory with WebClient.DownloadFile.
The code is (Action starts with a button-click to the one of two buttons on the page):

```
[HttpPost]
[MultiButton(MatchFormKey = "action", MatchFormValue = "ABC")]
public ActionResult ABC(TestFormModel model)
{
  string fileName = model.resultLink;
  try
     {
       string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
       System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(tempPath);
       fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(tempPath, fileName);

       Uri uri = new Uri(fileName);

       WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
       webClient.DownloadFile(uri, "FFF");                    
     }
  catch (Exception ex)
     { ... }                  
  return View(); 
}
```

Now I expected (reading "Downloads the resource with the specified URI to a local file." in the documentation) that the download dialog from browser will propmt. But NOTHING happens. No exception, no download dialog. What is wrong with my code?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "local file" in this case is a file on the server (Local to the web server) and not local to the end user.

The idea here is that once you've downloaded a resourced from one location to your local server, you can redirect the user to that downloaded file and, if their browser is set up to do so, a dialog will appear allowing them to save the file.

By the looks of it you're downloading the file *from* your local server *to* your local server.

If the file already exists on your local server you can simply redirect the user at the end of your action method and their browser will handle the rest.

```
return Redirect(fileUrl);
```

Comment: Hallo Jamie, yes I'm trying to download the file from my local Server (also from the iis express working on the localserver) to my local Server (to the local PC, and I like that the Browser ask me, in which Directory). In Java it is not the problem, if the Server is the localhost. Is it not possible in C# to develop software localy? I can't belive it! Thank you. Mark

Comment: I think there's a bit of confusion as to what "Local" means. The `DownloadFile` method downloads the file to the server. Local means the local server, not the user using the website. So the user will never see a download dialog because the file is being sent to the server, not to the user. You have to send the file to the user by redirecting them to the file. Their browser will then handle the download dialog. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hallo Jamie, you are right, I definitely misunderstood DownloadFile. I like to realise the download Dialog for the client's browser. But return Redirect(fileUrl); also don't work, I get the next Action-Page but no download Dialog. And it is no exception.

Comment: Hallo Jamie, I tryed return File(fileName, "application/pdf"); This is almost the Thing, I Need. But I get NOT THE Dialog, but the pdf-file opens INSIDE of the browser. The one Thing, I Need now is, that the browser DO NOT SHOW the File, but only prompt download Dialog. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Mark. There's a 3 parameter signature for `File` that will force the download rather than the default behavior. This third param adds a `content-disposition` and `filename` header to the response which is what forces the download.

Comment: Hallo Jamie, thanks a lot! It works with third Parameter (as File Name).